# In Spring Security , when users has same username, any problem will cause?

Tags: spring, security, userdetailsservice

All online tutorials are similar ， step by step , but that's not what i need, you know, the current system usually requires multiple login methods: SMS, email, etc, not just login with username and password, taking a step back, even if we log in with a username, won't there be users with the same username?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking here, but usernames are unique and must be unique.  You can allow multiple ways to authenticate the same user, password, sso, SMS, etc.